# jQuery bind event sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**EDIT: The problem is that I used `.select()` instead of `.find();`**

I have this simple jQuery code (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/znstj/)

```
<div class = "someclass"><button class = "myclass">clickme</button></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.someclass').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() { console.log('red'); });    
    $('.myclass').bind('click', function() { console.log('green'); });
});
</script>
```

Why on earth does "green" always print before "red"? (and how would I change this to make 'red' appear before 'green'?)

Comment: what do you think that `.select('.myclass')` call is doing?

Comment: What is `.select('.myclass')` suppose to do there? Maybe you meant to use `.find('.myclass')` ?

Comment: ok, I thought it selects all the "myclass" children from "someclass" but apparently this is not true, coming from a prototype background I made this mistake

Comment: I would leave this up, it was a perfectly valid question and an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your `.select()` call is a no-op - in jQuery it's used to register a handler for the `onselect` event!

Since `.select()` is a chaining function that returns the original object on which it was called, the result is that you've bound the first `click` handler to the outer `.someclass` div.

What you're therefore seeing is the effect of *bubbling*, the click is hitting the button first ("green") and then bubbling up to its parent ("red"), in that order.

If the intent of your `.select()` call was to bind the first click handler just to the button, then you should have used `.children('.myclass')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your own custom functions:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){ 
      $(this).trigger('green');
      $(this).trigger('red');
   })

$('.myclass').bind('green', function(e) {
   console.log('green');
});

...
```

BUT, `bind` is deprecated in favor of `.on()` -> [http://api.jquery.com/on/](http://jquery.com/on)